# React Native Expo How to upload an image to Firebase using expo Image picker

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage, react-native-image-picker

I'm trying to upload an Image to my firebase but I can't figure it out.

This is my code

```
_pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
        this.uploadImage(result.uri, 'test-image')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('it work')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('it does not work')
                console.error(error)
            })
    }
};

uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = response.blob();

    const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(`images/${imageName}`);
    return ref.put(blob);
}
```

I'm getting this error.

```
FirebaseStorageError {
 "code_": "storage/invalid-argument",
 "message_": "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.",
 "name_": "FirebaseError",
 "serverResponse_": null,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
`const blob = await response.blob();`
```

Instead of:

`const blob = response.blob();`

to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try `var ref= firebase.storage().ref().child('images/'+imageName)` instead of yours